# What are the elements of Z/10Z and of Z/2Z×Z/5Z, and identify which elements correspond under the map g from Z/10Z to Z/2Z × Z/5Z.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What are the elements of Z/10Z and of Z/2Z×Z/5Z,

and identify which elements correspond under the map g from Z/10Z to Z/2Z × Z/5Z.

I know the elements of Z/10Z are {1,3,7,9}, is that the same for Z/2Z×Z/5Z?

I need help with the second part of the question.

Comment: The elements of $\mathbb{Z}/10 \mathbb{Z}$ are the equivalence classes represented by $\{ 0,1,2,3,\ldots,8,9\}$. The invertible elements of $\mathbb{Z} / 10 \mathbb{Z}$ are $\{1 ,3,7,9\}$.

Comment: i editted your previous question. I'm sure you can look it up and edit this.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 3):

The elements of $\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z$ are the remainder classes modulo $10$ (hence subsets of $\Bbb Z$), and *all* the ten of them, naturally represented by $0,1,2,\dots,9$ [or, by $-4,\dots,0,+5$].

The elements of $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ are the 'set of even integers' (represented mostly by $0$) and the 'set of odd integers' (represented mostly by $1$).

The elements of $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\ \times\ \Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$ are *ordered pairs* $(u,v)$ where $u\in\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ and $v\in\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$.

Giving a homomorphism $g:\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z\ \to\ \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$ is equivalent to giving its projections $g_1:\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z\ \to\ \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ and $g_2:\Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z\ \to\ \Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$.